# Ruby loading config (yaml) file in same dir as source

Tags: ruby, path, yaml, configuration-files

in HOME/path_test/ I have:

load_test.rb:

```
require 'yaml'
cnf = YAML::load(File.open('config.yml'))
puts cnf['Hello']
```

config.yml:

```
Hello: world!!!
```

when in HOME/path_test/ I get as expected:

```
-bash-3.2$ ruby load_test.rb 
world!!!
```

when in HOME/ (cd ..) I get

```
-bash-3.2$ ruby path_test/load_test.rb 
path_test/load_test.rb:3:in `initialize': No such file or directory - config.yml     (Errno::ENOENT)
    from path_test/load_test.rb:3:in `open'
    from path_test/load_test.rb:3:in `<main>'
```

Which is correct behavior, but not what I had wished for :)

Is there a way to load the .yml file relative to the source file, and not relative to the current working DIR??

Solution (load_Test.rb):

```
require 'yaml'
fn = File.dirname(File.expand_path(__FILE__)) + '/config.yml'
cnf = YAML::load(File.open(fn))
puts cnf['Hello']
```

Answer (score 89, accepted):

You should get path of the current file by:

```
cnf = YAML::load_file(File.join(File.dirname(File.expand_path(__FILE__)), 'config.yml'))
```

**EDIT:**

Since Ruby 2.0 you can simplify that and use:

```
cnf = YAML::load_file(File.join(__dir__, 'config.yml'))
```

Comment: Thanks (one ')' too much at the end :] ) just what I needed

Comment: This is the full solution (split on 2 lines for clarity):

`    require 'yaml'
    fn = File.dirname(File.expand_path(__FILE__)) + '/config.yml'
    cnf = YAML::load(File.open(fn))
    puts cnf['Hello']`

Comment: I had to use YAML::load_file for this to work for me. YAML::load just returned a string representing the results for File.join.

Comment: For the 2.0 solution, doesn't this need to be `nf = YAML::load_file(File.join(__dir__, 'config.yml'))` (with lowercase `__dir__`)?

Comment: `__dir__` represents the path of the current file being executed?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15190700/why-is-file-uppercase-and-dir-lowercase - it is method that do the same as `File.dirname(File.expand_path(__FILE__))`. So no, it is directory of *this* file, not executed one.

Comment: To get path to current file executed then you should use `File.dirname(File.expand_path($0))`.

Comment: It's preferable in ruby to call class methods with `.` and not `::`, so `YAML.load_file` would be better.