# YAML.load_file issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a bestiary.yml and test.rb in one directory, and when I try loading my .yml file like that

```
got_data_1 = YAML.load_file('bestiary.yml')
```

it gives me a

```
/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych.rb:471:in `initialize': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen
```

error. But when I try launching this

```
got_data = YAML.load(File.open(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'bestiary.yml')))
```

everything works fine. Why load_file method doesn't work and what's the difference between this two methods? 
Thank you

Comment: See also [*Ruby loading config (yaml) file in same dir as source*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8878389/ruby-loading-config-yaml-file-in-same-dir-as-source).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose both files are in the same directory but you are not launching the rb file from that directory. If I'm correct try this as well

```
got_data_1 = YAML.load_file(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'bestiary.yml'))
```

This work just if the yml file is in the same directory AND you launch the rb file from that directory also

```
got_data_1 = YAML.load_file('bestiary.yml')
```